# Attempt to install `sqlite3` for Electron app resulting in incorrect path

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and Node.  I'm trying to build an app that will include a sqlite3 database, just for the experience of doing it (this will not be my last stackoverflow post on this project).

Within the project folder I run:

```
npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev
npm install sqlite3 --save-dev
```

And the contents of `node_modules` populates correctly it seems.  When I attempt to run the application with `electron .` I get an error indicating I that the module can't be found at `~/Programming/DemoCode/Electron/electron-officers/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.2-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node`.

The actual path is `~/Programming/DemoCode/Electron/electron-officers/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v48-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node`.  If I go in and manually change the path to be correct the application runs, but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3` is a native Node module and as such must be rebuilt to target the Electron version you're using, [the docs explain how to do this](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/).

Comment: I have previously followed the instructions at that location under the title "Installing modules and rebuilding for Electron" and the problem persists.